# Visual studio Exceldatareader : Search for only rows who contain a specific value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exceldatareader

I was wondering. If you have 50 sheets in 1 file and you have little tables in different sheets with values like 'column 1' and 'column 2'. Is it possible to look up these sheets by these values? I would add the tables to a list and then search for the values in those tables to get them out and put them in another file.

I got the datasheet part and all that, but i'm wondering how I can filter just the tables I need, then the colums I need in those tables and then loop those colums to find the values I need.
I've edited this post to get a better picture.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX1K2.png)

I need the values under the field that contain values 'column1', 'column2' and 'column3'

This multiple times, but you don't know in what sheet and how many times or on what row they are. So i want to find those tables and get the data.

I don't need code for the dataset. This I allready figured out. I have the dataset, I just can't figure out the filtering.

Comment: So you’re looking for two successive cells with the text ‘cost’ and ‘client’? Can’t you just loop through? And once you find them, read the values in those columns in the rows below until you reach some kind of ‘stop’ value, like an empty cell?

Comment: So I loop all tables and look for value 'cost' with **DataTable.Select(string filterExpression)**, i read the row value and then loop trough the sheet behind the cell value untill i find a empty cell?